# Facebook Webhook on adding/editing/deleting a comment in a group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, webhooks, zapier, facebook-webhooks

Is it possible to have Webhooks for adding/deleting/editing a comment on posts in a groups feed, using the Webhooks of Facebook, or services like Zapier.

Comment: There is no webhook functionality for groups _at all_ right now. (Only workplace groups are covered, but that’s a different thing than normal groups.)